# Problems linking hokuyo_node to hector_slam and showing data on rviz

Tags: ros, navigation, mapping, hokuyo-node, hector-mapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Sorry but i'm new to ros and i'm having problems linking the data received by hokuyo_node and to hector_mapping. My goal is show the pose of the LIDAR in rviz using the data received by the hokuyo (the LIDAR isn't connected to a robot yet, it is just on a table, i'm rotating it so i cant see the laser scan in rviz). I don't know if i need to create a new package for this or if i can work without it. Can someone help me?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/219621/problems-linking-hokuyo_node-to-hector_slam-and-showing-data-on-rviz/) by [andrefc](https://answers.ros.org/users/24722/andrefc/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2015-10-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!,

I am quite sure you dont need to create any node to connect Hokuyo with Hector_mapping, since there are already implemented nodes for that, for the Hokuyo you can find the driver code [here](https://github.com/ros-drivers/hokuyo_node).

So now the only thing you have to do is to make sure that both of your nodes have the correct configuration to work and communicate together.

First of all you have to make sure of what you need to make hector mapping work, you can find all that info in the [wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/hector_mapping). As you can see there, for that you only need to publish the tf transformation between the link of the sensor, and the base of the robot (since you dont have a robot, i think that you should create some kind of artificial frame at the base of the sensor as base_link), for that you can use robot_state_publisher.

Then you have to make sure that the sensor is broadcasting to the same topic, the hector_mapping node is listening to. I think Hokuyo publish by default in the topic "sensor_msgs/LaserScan" , the same one that uses the Hector_mapping node, so this shouldn't be a problem. And if all of this is correct i think it should work.

Your question was not quite specific, so i dont know if this is what you were looking for. Hope this helps!!

---

Originally posted by [donmrsir](https://answers.ros.org/users/19553/donmrsir/) with karma: 363 on 2015-10-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [andrefc](https://answers.ros.org/users/24722/andrefc/) on 2015-10-22**:
Thank you for your answer! You were right i was not quite especific, sorry about that. I resolved my problem simply by modifying the hector_mapping launch file, changing the base_frame to "laser" and pub_map_odom_transform to "false". Now i can see in rviz the position and orientation of the laser.